# Convert JSON service to JSONP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, web-services, jsonp

I have a webservice written in PHP that returns JSON. Problem is that it needs to work cross-domain, so i will have to use JSONP. I already got it to work with JSON on the same server, but i'm failing to convert this using JSONP so i can use the service in an app. Here is the webservice:

```
<?php



// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("mysqlstudent","sylvainvansteela","zei8quea0eeP","sylvainvansteela");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {

  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

  } else {

 $mysqlstring = "SELECT * FROM customers";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$mysqlstring);
 $rows = array();

 $i = 0;
 while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[$i]["id"] = $r[0];
    $rows[$i]["email"] = $r[1];
    $i++;
}
header('content-type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');

$json = json_encode($rows);

echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.$json.')';

  }

 ?>
```

Here is how I try to call this using jQuery:

```
function getCustomers(){

        var url = 'http://student.howest.be/sylvain.vansteelandt/fedex/server/getcustomers.php';

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://student.howest.be/sylvain.vansteelandt/fedex/server/getcustomers.php',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) { alert(data); },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Error ' + textStatus); alert('Error Thrown ' + errorThrown); }
});

};

getCustomers();
```

The error the ajax function throws is:
Error Thrown Error: jQuery171046326508649762743_1375704060400 was not called

So I'd like to know if i'm doing something wrong with the webservice or with the client code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I call http://student.howest.be/sylvain.vansteelandt/fedex/server/getcustomers.php?callback=x I do not get a JSONP return

Comment: @mplungjan well yeah, i'd like to know how i can get this script to return JSONP

Comment: By returning the callback. Your code posted here shows it would, but the code on your server does not. 
Change echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.$json.')'; to echo "Here goes callback".$_GET['callback'] . '('.$json.')'; to see if you actually updated the server code?

Comment: can you check/var_dump to see what are you getting in $_GET ?

Comment: also include cache:false in your jquery, so that you get new data.